# When trying to sign git commit I get error gpg: DBG: Using CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB flag

Tags: github, gpg-agent

I'm trying to make a new singed commit, but I get an error :

```
gpg: DBG: Using CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB flag
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
gpg: keydb_search failed: No agent running
gpg: skipped "C4583B304CDA4CA0": No agent running
gpg: signing failed: No agent running
error: gpg failed to sign the data
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The only thing that I can say is that the `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` is not the error, only a message (possibly a warning) I get the message regularly when signing commits but they are successfully signed

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the logs you shared it seems that **no agent is running**. I have the same issue, and since I set up Kleopatra to handle my certificates, I solved this by ensuring that Kleopatra is up and running whenever I'm about to commit something. Then commit singing works again.

I don't know what OS you are on, but try to **run the ssh-agent** again, or make sure it launches at startup.